# Ionic 2 How to style <ion-item> window

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I´ve been trying to style the "" window that pops out whenever I press on it. So my HTML code is this:

```css
page-about {
  
}
```

```html
<!--HTML about.html -->
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Toppings</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="toppings">
    <ion-option>Bacon</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Black Olives</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Extra Cheese</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Mushrooms</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Pepperoni</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Sausage</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

I kinda want to reduce the width and height of the window that pops out.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would simply open up page in chrome developer toolbar, find relevant tag which changes the style with specificity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="toppings" class="selectClass">
    <ion-option>Bacon</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Black Olives</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Extra Cheese</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Mushrooms</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Pepperoni</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Sausage</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

In your .sass file add this

```
.selectClass {
    max-width:100px !important;
}
```